# Rails 4.2 - Made a 'services' directory for PORO helpers but console/controllers etc don't see it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have some logic that is going to manipulate data before starting a job queue. However, inside the controller and also in the rails console I cannot seem to access the classes. Example:

In `app/services/hobo_service.rb` I have

```
class HoboService
  def initialize
    @api = Hobos::Api.new
  end

  def run
    hobo
  end

  private

  attr_reader :api

  def hobo
    api.hobo
  end
end
```

However, if in my relevent controller I put

```
...
  def create
    @name = HoboService.new.run
  end
...
```

Raises an exception saying the object cannot be found.

It seems as if all in the `app` directory should be in the pipeline and available. What am I missing here? Haven't been on Rails since 3.2 until recently.

Comment: you restarted your server?

Comment: Yep, several times now :(

Comment: I can't reproduce this locally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why a subdirectory of app would be ignored, but let's try the simple solution- what happens when you add this to the Application class in your application.rb?

`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/services)`